# Direct3D11: Rendering 2D in 3D scene: how to make 2D objects not move on Viewport when camera changes position?

Tags: c++, 3d, 2d, directx, direct3d11

Images with examples of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kgdc.jpg

Hi,
I need some help with rendering 2D objects in 3D scene with 3D camera. I think I managed to solve 2D coordinates with LH world coordinates. However, my rendered 2D objects are in a correct place, only when camera is at `[0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f]` coordinates. In every other position, the location of 2D objects on scene is malformed. I think my matrices are screwed up, but don't know where to look further. I'd appreciate good ideas, please comment if something's missing for you, I'll edit the main post to provide you more information.

I'm using simple 3D color HLSL (VS and PS ver: 4.0) shader with alpha blending for the bigger triangle:

```
cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register( b0 )
{
    matrix World;
    matrix View;
    matrix Projection;
}
struct VS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};
struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

PS_INPUT VS ( VS_INPUT input )
{
    PS_INPUT output = (PS_INPUT)0;

    input.Pos.w = 1.0f;

    output.Pos = mul ( input.Pos, World );
    output.Pos = mul ( output.Pos, View );
    output.Pos = mul ( output.Pos, Projection );
    output.Color = input.Color;

    return output;
}

float4 PS ( PS_INPUT input ) : SV_Target
{
    return input.Color;
}
```

That's my Vertex data struct:

```
  struct Vertex
  {
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3 position;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4 color;

    Vertex() {};

    Vertex(DirectX::XMFLOAT3 aPosition, DirectX::XMFLOAT4 aColor) 
      : position(aPosition)
      , color(aColor) 
    {};
  };
```

Render call for object:

```
bool PrimitiveMesh::Draw()
{
  unsigned int stride = sizeof(Vertex);
  unsigned int offset = 0;

  D3DSystem::GetD3DDeviceContext()->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &iVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
  D3DSystem::GetD3DDeviceContext()->IASetIndexBuffer(iIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
  D3DSystem::GetD3DDeviceContext()->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

  return true;
}
```

Draw call with initialization:

```
    static PrimitiveMesh* mesh;
    if (mesh == 0)
    {
      std::vector<PrimitiveMesh::Vertex> vertices;
      mesh = new PrimitiveMesh();

      DirectX::XMFLOAT4 color = { 186 / 256.0f, 186 / 256.0f, 186 / 256.0f, 0.8f };
      vertices.push_back({ DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), color });
      vertices.push_back({ DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 600.0f, 0.0f), color });
      vertices.push_back({ DirectX::XMFLOAT3(800.0f, 600.0f, 0.0f), color });

      mesh->SetVerticesAndIndices(vertices);
    }
    // Getting clean matrices here:
    D3D::Matrices(world, view, projection, ortho);
    iGI->TurnZBufferOff();
    iGI->TurnOnAlphaBlending();
    mesh->Draw();
    XMMATRIX view2D = Camera::View2D();

    iColorShader->Render(iGI->GetContext(), 3, &world, &view2D, &ortho);
    iGI->TurnZBufferOn();
```

These are my 2D calculations for camera:

```
  up = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  lookAt = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  rotationMatrix = DirectX::XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // (pitch, yaw, roll);

  up = DirectX::XMVector3TransformCoord(up, rotationMatrix);
  lookAt = DirectX::XMVector3TransformCoord(lookAt, rotationMatrix) + position;
  view2D = DirectX::XMMatrixLookAtLH(position, lookAt, up);
```

I'll appreciate any help.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed my problem. For some weird reason, DirectXMath was generating false XMMATRIX. My `XMMatrixOrtographicLH()` was completely incorrect for good parameters. I solved my problem with classic definition of Ortohraphic matrix, [found in this article](http://www.codinglabs.net/article_world_view_projection_matrix.aspx) (definition in Fig. 10)

```
auto orthoMatrix = DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity();
orthoMatrix.r[0].m128_f32[0] = 2.0f / Engine::VideoSettings::Current()->WindowWidth();
orthoMatrix.r[1].m128_f32[1] = 2.0f / Engine::VideoSettings::Current()->WindowHeight();
orthoMatrix.r[2].m128_f32[2] = -(2.0f / (screenDepth - screenNear));
orthoMatrix.r[2].m128_f32[3] = -(screenDepth + screenNear) / (screenDepth - screenNear);
```

Answer (score 1):

With Shaders, you are not forced to use matrices, you have the flexibility to simplify the problem.

Let say you render 2d objects, using coordinates in pixels, the only requirement, is to scale offset them back into the normalized projective space.

A vertex shader could be as short as that :

```
cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register( b0 ) {
    float2 rcpDim; // 1 / renderTargetSize
}
PS_INPUT VS ( VS_INPUT input ) {
    PS_INPUT output;

    output.Pos.xy = input.Pos.xy * rcpDim * 2; // from pixel to [0..2]
    output.Pos.xy -= 1; // to [-1..1]
    output.Pos.y *= -1; // because top left in texture space is bottom left in projective space
    output.Pos.zw = float2(0,1);
    output.Color = input.Color;
    return output;
}
```

You can of course build a set of matrices achieving the same result with your original shader, just set World and View to identity and projection to an ortho projection with `XMMatrixOrthographicOffCenterLH(0,width,0,height,0,1)`. But as you are beggining with 3D programming, you will soon have to learn to deal with multiple shaders anyway, so take it as an exercice.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I've managed to solve it myself. For some weird reason, however unbelievable that is, my XMMatrixOrtographicProjectionLH was completely incorrect, I had to make it myself, that fixed the problem completely. I applied [this](http://www.codinglabs.net/article_world_view_projection_matrix.aspx) matrix definition from under Fig. 9.

Answer (score 0):

galop1n give a good solution but on my system

`cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register( b0 ) {
    float2 rcpDim; // 1 / renderTargetSize
}`

NEED to be a multiple of 16 for made like here:

```
struct VS_CONSTANT_BUFFER
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 rcpDim;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 rcpDim2;
};

// Supply the vertex shader constant data.
VS_CONSTANT_BUFFER VsConstData;
VsConstData.rcpDim = { 2.0f / w,2.0f / h};

// Fill in a buffer description.
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbDesc;
ZeroMemory(&cbDesc, sizeof(cbDesc));
cbDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(VS_CONSTANT_BUFFER);
cbDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
cbDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
cbDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
cbDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
cbDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;

// Fill in the subresource data.
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
ZeroMemory(&InitData, sizeof(InitData));
InitData.pSysMem = &VsConstData;
InitData.SysMemPitch = 0;
InitData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

// Create the buffer.
HRESULT hr = pDevice->CreateBuffer(&cbDesc, &InitData,
    &pConstantBuffer11);
```

or aligned

```
__declspec(align(16))
struct VS_CONSTANT_BUFFER
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 rcpDim;
};
```